# Flutter:Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter

I don't know what is wrong with this, but when I click on the logout button I get this error.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════ Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)....following is my logout button

```
ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: const Text("Logout"),
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.pop(context);
              // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  '/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();
            },
          ),
```

[image: error]in the above image I guess the error is coming from provider getVehicles therefore I am pasting that code too

```
@override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ApiCalls>(context, listen: false).getVehicles(context);
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: the error is expected because you are calling a function after your widget is detached.

Comment: ok can you say me how to dispose function after widget is detached ...what should I do now how to call a function when I open a screen

Comment: there is no such thing as disposing a function. you have to call your log out first and make sure there is no running behind the scene before clearing all your routes then redirect the user to the screen you want.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked problem is first I am clearing the routes and I am calling logout now I am loging out first and clearing routes